# Why do sqlite columns have different names for views and tables?

Tags: c++, sql, c, sqlite

For this sample database:

```
create table atable (
  textfield varchar(256)
);

create view aview as select T.textfield from atable T;
```

and these selects:

```
select T.textfield from atable T;

select T.textfield from aview T;
```

calling sqlite's `sqlite3_column_name(...)` yields different results for the select on view and on table. In case of table the the alias is not included, in case of view it is.

Here are the results:

```
table query - sqlite3_column_name (db, 0) -> "textfield"
view query - sqlite3_column_name (db, 0) -> "T.textfield"
```

Why are these different?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly, SQLITE provides no guarantees to the column name returned by `sqlite_3_column_name` unless you specifically provide the name using `AS` keyword.

From [`sqlite3_column_name`](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_name.html)  function documentation:

> The name of a result column is the value of the "AS" clause for that
>   column, if there is an AS clause. If there is no AS clause then the
>   name of the column is unspecified and may change from one release of
>   SQLite to the next.

Therefore you have to manually specify the column names if you want to depend on the value returned. Change your queries to :

```
select T.textfield as textfield from atable T;
select T.textfield as textfield from aview T;
```

and in both cases `sqlite3_column_name` will return `textfield`.